# Databinding in Xamarin.Forms using a RealObject

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, realm

Apps running very smoothly but I have decided to add to it. I currently have an APR Calculator but I want users to be able to save APRs. so I currently had my app all in the one class as it was pretty small. The way it was set out was using MVVM. Like I said I now want users to be able to save APRs so I installed RealmDB, I've created a class "APR" and pasted my whole MainWindowViewModel code in to that class I've created. APR class inherits Realm Object I have created an instance of the APR class in MainWindowViewModel but the current bindings in my XAML cannot find my properties... Below is the code for my MainWindowViewModel.

namespace APRooved.ViewModels
{

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    APR InstanceOne = new APR();

}
```

}

I'm sure this is just something silly I'm missing, If someone can point me in the right direction It would be much appreciated.

Comment: you can only bind to public properties.  `InstanceOne` is a field, not a property, and not public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do this would be initialise your APR class in the constructor

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public APR InstanceOne { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel(){
        InstanceOne = new APR();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can only bind to public properties. `InstanceOne` is a field, not a property, and not public

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public APR InstanceOne { get; set; } = new APR();
}
```